# Wired that ttk Label textvariable can't be displayed in class properly

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, label, ttk

I am totally newbie of Python. However i have to use python 3 to do some projects. I am really confused by ttk.Label with textvariable. Below is my codes.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class new_label:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.label_var = StringVar()

        ttk.Label(self.master, text="iii").grid(row=0, sticky = "w")
        self.create_label()

    def create_label(self):
        self.l1 = ttk.Label(f,
                           textvariable = self.label_var,
                           foreground = "red",)
        self.l1.grid(row=1)
        self.label_var.set("First Label")
        print(self.l1.cget("text"))

r=Tk()
r.title("My Label Update")

f=ttk.Frame(r)
f.grid(row=0)

new_label(f)
r.mainloop()
```

In my codes I add a print and it can print the text well. However the text can't display out and there is no any message of any errors. I do need someone to help for this issue.
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't keeping a reference so the instance of `new_label`, so the python [garbage collector](https://stackify.com/python-garbage-collection/) is collecting it. The ttk widgets are particularly sensitive to the use of garbage-collected `StringVar` instances.

The simple solution is to keep a reference to your instance of `new_label`:

```
x = new_label(f)
```

Comment: Hi Bryan, thanks for your reply. It is really good for me to know python garbage collector at beginning of my studying. Your solution is workable. Your help is amazing.